# Why does my promise resolve earlier than expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, settimeout

I have adjusted the post again and added most of the code. I have removed some of the unnecessary code.
The point is that I have several items for which I want to call an endpoint one after the other.
Since the API likes to get an error, I want the callTornApi method to only resolve when either 5 attempts have failed or a result has been achieved.

My entry point:

```js
/**
   * Iterate over the item IDs.
   * For each ID, call the `getItemUpdated` function with the ID, 'TornFlipBot', and a callback function.
   * The callback function calls the `informUser` function with the client, the item ID, and the active users.
   * If there's an error, it's caught and logged to the console.
   */
  for (let i = 0; i < itemIds.length; i++) {
    const res = await getItemUpdated(itemIds[i]).catch(async () => {
      console.log('Error.. Retrying..')

      // @ts-ignore
      await wait(5000)
      i--
    })

    if (res) await informUser(client, itemIds[i])
  }
```

Call the getLowestListing method. The promise is resolved if the data was successful and other checks matched.

getItemUpdated

```js
const getItemUpdated = async (itemId) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await JSON.stringify(await api.market.getLowestListing(itemId))
    
    // i deleted some code here...
  })
}
```

This is only an intermediate stage, as two API calls are necessary.

getLowestListing

```js
async getLowestListing(itemId: number): Promise<LowestListing | null> {
    const bazaarItems = await this.bazaar.getItems(itemId, 1)

    if (this.api.error) {
      return null
    }
    
    // i deleted some code here
  }
```

The final method is then called here, which is only resolved if data is available or after 5 failures at the latest.

getItems

```js
async getItems(itemId: number, limit?: number): Promise<IItemMarketItem[] | null> {
    const res = await this.api.callTornApi(`/market/${itemId}`, {
      key: this.api.getKey(),
      selections: 'bazaar',
      limit
    })

    return res?.bazaar
  }
```

callTornApi

```js
async callTornApi (url: string, params?): Promise<object> {
    let finished = false

    // While the API call is not finished and the number of retries is less than 5
    while(!finished && this.retries < 5) {
      if (this.debug) {
        console.log('Calling Torn API... ', url, params)
      }

      const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
        params
      })

      if (data.error) {
        if (this.debug) console.log('Wrapper API Error: ', data.error.error, ' Code: ', data.error.code, ' Retries: ', this.retries)

        this.error = {
          code: data.error.code,
          message: data.error.error
        }

        if (data.error.code === 2) {
          this.removeKey(params.key)
        }

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
          this.retries++
          resolve(null)
        }, this.retryTimeout))
      } else {
        this.retries = 0
        this.error = undefined
        finished = true
        return data
      }
    }

    if (this.retries >= 5) {
      this.retries = 0
      return null
    }

  }
```

Comment: Ok then the timeout would work, but still the while loop does not run to the end. The method should only be resolved if retries >= 5 or data.error is false or null

Comment: **Your function has to return a promise** where you explicitly **either have to `resolve` the promise** by passing the received API data **or you have to reject the promise** due to having failed with the API call 5 times in a row.

Comment: Please help, but isnt the return data exactly this?

Comment: @OliverKhl "*Ok then the timeout would work*" - can you [edit] your question to show how you changed the code to make it work? "*but still the while loop does not run to the end.*" - how so?

Comment: @Bergi - edited

Comment: @OliverKhl Thanks. That code should work (although there are some possible simplifications), what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Also notice that this method shares its `.error` and `.retries` counter with other method calls on the same object. How often are you invoking it?

Comment: @Bergi the method is called in a for loop, but, and that was the goal, only after the call has been resolved.

Comment: Ill test it and get back, rn no possibility to check, thanks to you guys!

Comment: Please post the code of that loop. Did you `await` each call?

Comment: I added the whole code in the correct order of the calls

Comment: mixing async/await within .then and promise constructor is not a good idea - and especially this line `await JSON.stringify(await api.market.getLowestListing(itemId))` ... why bother stringifying something (note, no need to await an operation that isn't asynchronous) and discarding the result? makes zero sense to bother stringifying it if you aren't using the result

Comment: As i said i deleted some code here and there. At this point i need to compare two objects.